# No projects are found to import min3d

Tags: android, min3d

ive downloaded min3d min3dSampleProject1_020.apk

and im trying to import it to my eclipse but eclipse say no projects are found to import

just to add ive created to my local C:program files a folder named min3d and put what ive downloaded..,

### can anyone help me out..,!!

Comment: are you importing the apk file to your workspace?
I think You need to unzip the apk if you need to import it as a project to your workspace

Comment: yes!!

how can i unzip it?? the file is just .apk

Answer (score 3):

You cannot import a .apk file to Eclipse, you need to download the source code from:

http://code.google.com/p/min3d/

then import this project from Eclipse.

If you try to unzip a .apk file, you will only see the resources and the AndroidManifest.xml, but you will not see the src folder.

Comment: can you please explain how to import this in eclipse?